# Garbage value in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi guys I am having a very simple problem. 
I have created a class called PreferenceHelper and I have a static function as shown below

```
+ (int) getInt:(NSString *)key{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger value = [prefs integerForKey:key];
    if ([prefs valueForKey:key] == nil||key==nil) {
        return 0;
    }
    int valInt = (int)value;
    return valInt;
}
```

I invoke the above code from another block of code from another class as mentioned below

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/scores"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              if (!error){
                                  int parseScore = [PreferenceHelper getInt:@"highscore"];
                              } else {
                                  NSLog(@"failed");
                              }
                          }];
```

When I debug towards the getInt function in PreferenceHelper the variable key(NSString *) loses its value and sometimes become nil. Also even if the value returned by the function is 0 , the value received by parseScore is a garbage value. anyone knows the reason?

Comment: FYI - In your `getInt:` method you really should have the `if` statement first. What's the point of checking the `key` after you use it? And you should also swap the two conditions in the `if`. And lastly, change `valueForKey:` to `objectForKey:`.

Comment: why don't you return 0 if key is nil? (instead of checking valueForKey?)

Comment: So you sometimes see that `key` is `nil` while `getInt:` is running? Is this the only place from which you call `getInt:`? That kind of thing shouldn’t be able to happen if you’re just passing in a string literal.

Comment: @maddy the code works perfectly if called outside normally. This happens only when this is triggered from a callback. Can this be the reason?

Comment: It looks wierd. does it have anything to do with block programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function looks a little overwrought. It will probably be more robust (and functionally identical) if it looks something like this:

```
+ (int) getInt:(NSString *)key
{
    if(!key)
        return 0;

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSInteger value = [prefs integerForKey:key];

    return (int)value;
}
```

Comment: It returns 0, but when I check the variable from the block where I called the function it has a garbage value.